# How to display the next item in array in a SwiftUI custom struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I am trying to display the next item in my SwiftUI custom struct without having to go back and select from the `List`. I am using below code:

```swift
func nextItem() -> ItemDetailView {
    let currentIndex = userData.itemArray.firstIndex(of: item) ?? -1
    var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
    nextIndex = userData.itemArray.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0
    return ItemDetailView(item: userData.itemArray[nextIndex])
}
```

This is how I call it attached to a `ScrollGroup`:

```swift
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
        self.nextItem()
    }) {
        Text("Next Item", comment: "Button label")
    })
```

This is my basic data struct:

```swift
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id &&
            lhs.itemOriginalText == rhs.itemOriginalText &&
            lhs.itemTransliteration == rhs.itemTransliteration &&
            lhs.hasNotes == rhs.hasNotes
    }
    
    let id: Int
    let itemMeta: ItemMeta
    let itemResolution: ItemResolution
    let itemOriginalText, itemTransliteration: String
    let itemTranslation: ItemTranslation
    let hasNotes: Bool
    let itemNotes: ItemNotes
}
```

This is my array variable:

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Item]()
}
```

These are the modifications to `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```swift
var userData = UserData()
let contentView = MainView().environmentObject(userData)
```

I get "Index out of range" each time I press the "Next" button I made. Also I get a warning that the `self.nextItem()` call is unused. I think I am not referring to the item properly, since below code works in a playground:

```swift
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

func nextItem(item: String) -> String {
    let currentIndex = array.firstIndex(of: item) ?? -1
    var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
    nextIndex = array.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0
    return array[nextIndex]
}

nextItem(item: "5")
```

I've also created an example program here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9b265502387c810da37ffebddb5c427620200620145511/1be0c444122229a2d2cfc0eb8a3550d620200620145527/09f682

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We'll need to see your user data struct and the call site of `nextItem()` to really help, but for starters, you're doing your index work on `itemArray` but do the final subscript on `items`.

Comment: @andyvn22, that was a simplification error, fixed and added the other info.

Comment: in playground version, you have `let currentIndex = ... ?? -1`, but in the broken version you have `let currentIndex = .... ?? 0`

Comment: @NewDev - sorry, it's an overlook. I was experimenting, and both do not work. It's supposed to be `-1` for correct output.

Comment: please consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Chris, added more relevant information.

Comment: Your example is still not compilable....

Comment: @Chris created a reproducible example program: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9b265502387c810da37ffebddb5c427620200620145511/1be0c444122229a2d2cfc0eb8a3550d620200620145527/09f682

Comment: Your last two lines of `nextItem()` have a bug. You say "if nextIndex is a valid index, use it, otherwise use 0". But 0 could be out of bounds, if your array is empty. In situations like this, you should use the debugger to inspect the values, or use `print` to write things to console. For example, if you add a line to nextItem like `print("itemArray.count = \(userData.itemArray.count), nextIndex = \(nextIndex)")` it may show you what the problem is.